# How to calculate hypothesis space

Tags: machine-learning, combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate the size of the hypothesis space of a function F. This function takes $N$ binary inputs and outputs a single binary classification.

With $N$ binary inputs, then the size of the domain must be $2^N$. Then, I would think that for each of these possible $2^N$ instances there must be two hypotheses (one for each output). This would make the total number of hypotheses equal to $2 \times (2^N)$.

I have read from other sources that the correct number of hypotheses is actually $2^{(2^N)}$. What is the mistake in my thinking?

Comment: Could you please explain how you obtain the value of $2\times(2^N)$?  That number does not appear to follow from the information you gave.  Perhaps a complete enumeration of the cases when $N=2$ would clarify things.

Comment: My thinking was that each combination of the N binary inputs could yield a result of either true or false (a binary output). With two possible outputs for each of the 2^N possible function evaluations, I calculated there must be 2*(2^N) different hypotheses. I hope that explains my thinking better.

Comment: Please revisit your calculation, because it is incorrect.  Explicit consideration of the case $N=2$ may help clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

In general, whenever we have a function $f: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, the function can be considered as an element of the set $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{D}$ (called the [function space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space)).  The set of *all possible* functions with domain $\mathcal{D}$ and codomain $\mathcal{C}$ is the full function space $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{D}$.  Each function in the space can be considered as a list of outputs for each of the inputs --- the list has $|\mathcal{D}|$ elements and each element takes on one of $|\mathcal{C}|$ possible outputs.  Consequently, using a simple application of the [multiplication principle of counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product), we have:

$$\begin{align}
\text{No. of possible functions with domain } \mathcal{D} \text{ and codomain } \mathcal{C} 
&= \underbrace{|\mathcal{C}| \times \cdots \times |\mathcal{C}|}_{|\mathcal{D}| \text{ times}} \\[12pt]
&= |\mathcal{C}|^{|\mathcal{D}|}. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Now, you have already correctly determined that there are $2^n$ possible inputs in the domain of the function, so we have $\mathcal{D} = 2^n$ in the present case.  For every possible input in the domain the function output takes on one of two binary values, so we have $|\mathcal{C}| = 2$.  Consequently, in this case we have:

$$\text{No. of possible functions with domain } \mathcal{D} \text{ and codomain } \mathcal{C} = |\mathcal{C}|^{|\mathcal{D}|} = 2^{2^n}. $$

Comment: Your answer requires a a knowledge of set theory and would be confusing to someone who would not start "counting" from zero. I am not familiar with using domain and codomain in the context of set theory, so I do not fully understand your explanation. It is no doubt correct, but accessibility may be an issue.

Comment: That is true, but I think this question is inherently a question about function spaces, which are generally explained in terms of sets.  In order for the OP to obtain a good knowledge of this issue, I think he will ultimately need to read some material on function spaces and the rules of counting sets.

Comment: I agree, but other people read this as well, and not everyone, e.g., me, wants to learn about set language. There is nothing wrong with your answer, nor with mine, the only difference is jargon. I tried for accessibility, you tried for precision of set language, question of taste really.

Comment: P.S. +1 for your answer.

Comment: I like the fact that you have given a non-set based answer (+1).  One of the nice things about having multiple answers is that you get explanations pitched with different levels of assumed knowledge and rigour.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the output as being a lock (0 closed, 1 opened) that is potentially opened by keys. That is, there might be no combination that can open the lock, or as many as $2^n$ keys that can open it. If the lock can be opened by only one key, then counting in binary it is some number between $0000\dots0000$ and $1111\dots1111$ for a binary number of length $n$, and there are $2^n$ of those. Next we ask how may combinations of two keys can open the lock and there are $\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\2\end{array}\right)$ of those.

In general, we are adding up combinations

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\0\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\1\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\2\end{array}\right)+\dots+\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\2^n-1\end{array}\right)+\left(\begin{array}{c}2^n\\2^n\end{array}\right).$$

Finally, as order does not matter, we can use the binomial theorem (see e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003038/373043)) to get
$${m \choose 0} + {m \choose 1} + {m \choose 2} + \dots + {m \choose m} = 2^m,$$ which substituting $m=2^n$ leads us to $2^{2^n}$, which is the answer you read.

Comment: @Sycorax Like this answer better?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for the edit, but I'm curious, why improve an answer, which implies that you follow what is being said to the point of wanting to say it better, and then not upvote it?

Comment: Hi @Carl: Glad you liked the edit.  I haven't upvoted because I'm still undecided on whether I like this answer.  While I like the attempt to use an example, I'm not sure if the keys/locks analogy really makes function spaces easier or harder to understand.  I've just upvoted a couple of your other answers in the meantime, while I think more about it.  (Since my edit was purely on formatting and syntactical grounds, it does not really imply a like or dislike of the answer; I just wanted to make the formatting nicer.)

Answer (score -1):

To calculate the Hypothesis Space:

[image]

if we have the given image above we can then figure it out the following way.

1. Count the number of attributes or features. In this case, we have four features or (4).
2. Analyze or if given what are the values corresponding to each feature (e.g. binary, or many different inputs). In this particular case, we have binary values (0/1).

   ```
   Hence, 2^4 = 16.
   ```
3. So for each of the 2^4 attributes, the outputs can take 0 or 1.

   ```
   Therefore, 2^(2^4) = 65536 ways.
   ```